# Bridge theme + woocommerce. Single product tabs are generating inside the summary div

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

in the single product page. I cant move the product tab out of the summary div. Which makes it impossible for me to apply the required styling. this is my code for content-single-product.php

```
<div class="product-summary">
                <div class="summary entry-summary">
                    <?php
                    /**
                     * woocommerce_single_product_summary hook.
                     *
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
                     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
                     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
                     */
                    do_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary');
                    ?>
                </div><!-- .summary -->
            </div><!-- .product-summary -->
        </div><!-- .product-container -->

        <div class="product-tabs">
            <?php
            /**
             * Hook: woocommerce_after_single_product_summary.
             *
             * @hooked woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs - 10
             */
            do_action('woocommerce_after_single_product_summary');
            ?>
        </div><!-- .product-tabs -->
```

the product tab div is empty on the frontend and the tabs are being created inside summary div.

I have tried to remove the tabs from the woocommerce_single_product_summary hook but it doesnt work.
then i tried to relocate it. Any help?

```
function relocate_product_tabs() {
    // Remove the product tabs from the woocommerce_single_product_summary hook
    remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 60 );

    // Add the product tabs to the woocommerce_after_single_product_summary hook
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );
}
add_action( 'init', 'relocate_product_tabs' );
```